# Get error while installing react-notifications-component package with React 18

Tags: reactjs, react-18

I used `react-notifications-component` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-notifications-component)) before and it was working fine. but recently I tried to install it with react 18 and I got this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: code-challenge-front@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.1" from react-notifications-component@3.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-notifications-component
npm ERR!   react-notifications-component@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

is there any solution? or I have to use another package?

Comment: have you tried deleting your `npm_modules` directory and re-installing everything with yarn?

Answer (score 5):

**react-notifications-component@3.4.1** is using peer dependencies of **react@"^17.0.1"**

If you want to use **react-notifications-component@3.4.1** then you have to use **react@"^17.0.1"** otherwise you can not use it with **react@"^18.0.0"** till **react-notifications-component** provides new version support with react 18.

Alternatively, you can use `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that and there is no solution for it right now... maybe in future...

https://github.com/teodosii/react-notifications-component/issues/152

you can use another package(recommended)
don't downgrade your react version(not a good solution)

Answer (score 0):

Well I got this error today so instead of downloading another package or downgrading my react version I tried to get a custom solution for this using css. Since i wanted to use this package to show notificationcount on recieving new notification, here is how i achieved the desired result.

> Blockquote

JSX code:

```
<div>
       {notification.length > 0 && (
         <div className="notification-badge">
              <span className="badge">    
                  {notification.length}
              </span>
          </div>
          )}
   </div>
```

> Blockquote

CSS :

```
.notification-badge {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0px 5px 0.5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).